# Sorting a nested list by second element of sub list without using built-in sorting functions, loops or recursion

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort a nested list by the second element without using sorting functions, loops or recursion. I know this is counter-intuitive but those are the restrictions I have to work with.

Example:

```py
L = [[101, 1], [99, 4], [85, 3], [415, 2], [380, 5], [75, 1]]
```

Expected output:

```py
[[[75, 1], [101, 1]], [415, 2], [85, 3], [99, 4], [380, 5]]
```

Is it possible? If not, could you point me in a direction that minimizes the use of those restrictions?

This is what I've tried but I had to use a loop. It also doesn't match the expected output exactly:

```
for i in L:
    L.remove(i)
    L.insert(i[1]-1, i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you always expecting a list of 6 items as input? Because if you need to be able to sort a list of variable length, not having access to `sorted`, loops or recursion is going to be a problem.

Comment: Do list comprehensions or other comprehensions count as loops for the purpose of your problem? How about `map` and `filter`? Is there any bound on the range of values which can occur in the list?

Comment: The list will be of variable length. The second element of each sub list will be a number between 1 and 50 inclusive but some numbers might be skipped (e.g. 1, 5, 30, 24). Map and filter are allowed, but not comprehensions of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works, but only by accident because the second element in each sub-list matches the list's indexes. It will break with a different list.

As you need to iterate over the list in order to compare each element, you need to resort to an algorithm that somehow loops.

To minimize the use of the restrictions, you could use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```py
L = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

This first sorts by the second number in each sub-list and if these numbers are the same it looks for the first number.

Comment: Isn't `sorted()` a *sorting function* as per OP question?

Comment: Read the whole question: "Is it possible? If not, could you point me in a direction that minimizes the use of those restrictions?"